# "High quality" option not working when uploading photos to a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-photos

Since 2018, the photos that I post on my Facebook page do not show in high resolution (~2048px) but are limited to low resolution (~1680px).

My photos aren't technically different from those I uploaded in large quantities in 2017. They are all above 2048px (for example one is 6720x4480, but once uploaded it shows as ~1680px).

I tried checking, unchecking, re-checking the "High quality" checkbox.
I tried doing it with Google Chrome, with Mozilla Firefox.
I tried uploading on one of my secondary pages.

(I upload on Windows desktop using the web version of Facebook.)

Why is this? How can I solve it?

---

Edit:
I also tried on another computer (With Win7 instead of Win10à

I just found one work around, but it's really annoying. I transferred one of the photos to my mobile phone and uploaded it using Chrome/Android web version of Facebook (I don't use the app). And I got that photo in ~2048px (max. resolution for Facebook to display). Now trying with a complete album ... Still hoping for a better solution so I don't post this as the answer for now.